# How to get DropDownList of all method & class declarations, so upon clicking on one it goes to it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins

It seems like all I use bookmarks for is to keep track of classes and methods. The problem is the line numbers become incorrect with editing. In addition, I have to manually set each bookmark. Is there a way to get a list of classes/methods within a file and click to go directly to it? Perhaps a plugin? Ideally I'd like a graphical representation that I could click on. Surely there is a plugin out there for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try C# Resharper http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ - it cost some license, but really worth it.

Comment: From within resharper, what is the command to list the classes and methods?

Comment: The shortcut I was looking for was alt \

Answer (score 2):

C# Resharper http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ -is best.

Answer (score 2):

People are suggesting Resharper already, but if you're using Visual Studio 2010 you could use a built in feature called **Naviagate To**

Just press:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

You can search for files/classes/objects/methods in your solution.

More information about Navigate To on this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2009/09/22/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx